# Android 30 Activity, how to make them into one

Tags: android, class, android-activity

Lets say, I want to make a quiz application. And I have 90 question - 3 question on each activity which is 30 activity. The way I know how to make all those Activities is to make a class for each of them. 30 class is a lot.

I'm using this method:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, Myclass.class));
```

What is the best way to make all those activities? Or can it all happen in one?

Thanks, comment if something is not explained clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that you could do is use a viewflipper within a single activity, to show a few different views there. Perhaps you could group your questions and use a single activity for each group, using the viewflipper for each group...

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I did not know about viewflippers. Looks like this may be it, going to test it tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would try to separate the data (the questions/answers) from the view (the activities) and use some `Intent.putExtra()` to open *one* quiz activity with a parameter to let it know which questions to load/show.

I am *not* sure, but I think that to share the questions data between the activity instances you could put them in a static variable in that activity.

If the plan is to go like `start quiz -> good answer -> start another quiz -> ...` then you might want to use [`android:noHistory`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist) to avoid leaving all old question activities in memory.

Comment: Thanks, I will still have to make 30 activties? Since Intent.putExtra just passes data? Correct me if I'm wrong. But thanks for the quick reply. :)

Comment: @Muazam well it's up to you to make the activity enough dynamic, so that writing one will allow you to use the extra parameter to load the three questions you want. This is pretty much what programming is about, it might need more design work, but once you have the solution you can reuse that.

Answer (score 0):

bigstones is correct. You need to separate the data from the Activity, and only create a single Activity. Then, you could have a button that they click when they've answered the set of questions they're currently viewing. Clicking that button would show a progress spinner, and then load the next 3 questions in the background. This should all be done with a single Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Mauzam.
I have a better solution .
You could also use one activity ,and use an Expandable List view instead.
this activity will have all the question in it  and when someone clicks on a particular question, this list view would expand to show the options and when answer is selected, u can store it somewhere.

here is an example:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html

I hope this helps!!